# Is there a way to sort objects within an object based on the value of one of the keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Okay, in my project im returned a json object like this:

```
  '18463685': {
    name: 'nidoranm',
    owner: '756135959145218128',
    level: 32,
    hpiv: 17,
    atkiv: 21,
    defiv: 16,
    spatkiv: 6,
    spdefiv: 10,
    speediv: 21,
    shiny: 'no',
    gender: 'male',
    totaliv: 91,
    uid: 18463685
  },
  '32075680': {
    name: 'golett',
    owner: '756135959145218128',
    level: 40,
    hpiv: 18,
    atkiv: 23,
    defiv: 7,
    spatkiv: 14,
    spdefiv: 12,
    speediv: 11,
    shiny: 'no',
    gender: 'unknown',
    totaliv: 85,
    uid: 32075680
  },
  '35339838': {
    name: 'exeggcute',
    owner: '756135959145218128',
    level: 20,
    hpiv: 13,
    atkiv: 13,
    defiv: 18,
    spatkiv: 11,
    spdefiv: 29,
    speediv: 5,
    shiny: 'no',
    gender: 'female',
    totaliv: 89,
    uid: 35339838
  },
  '35339838': {
    name: 'exeggcute',
    owner: '756135959145218128',
    level: 20,
    hpiv: 13,
    atkiv: 13,
    defiv: 18,
    spatkiv: 11,
    spdefiv: 29,
    speediv: 5,
    shiny: 'no',
    gender: 'female',
    totaliv: 89,
    uid: 35339838
  }
}
```

Each of these child objects within the parent object all share the same keys with different values, is there a way to sort the object based on something like its totaliv and be returned another object but with the child objects sorted based on value (descending)

My workspace is nodejs and im using javascript :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: @ThomasSablik Unfortunately not, im not trying to sort the object by keys but rather the value of one specific key thats in each object

Comment: But the answer is the same. It makes no sense to sort an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sort` function and then use the properties of each object

```js
const sorted = Object.keys(obj).sort((a, b) => {
  return obj[a].totaliv - obj[b].totaliv;
});
```

Gets all of the keys of the object

```js
Object.keys(obj)
```

Call the sort function on an array

```js
.sort((a, b) =>
```

Compare objects to sort them by `.totaliv`

```js
return obj[a].totaliv - obj[b].totaliv;
```

Sort Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/array/sort